# Meteor app very slow on Firefox with Firebug on Mac when other tabs before it

Tags: javascript, firefox, meteor, firebug

I have a [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) (v0.8.3) web app.

It runs smoothly on most modern browsers (including IE 9+ on a PC). However, on Firefox 31.0 on Mac OS 10.7.5 (with Firebug 2.0.4 installed), it sometimes runs excruciating slowly, and often brings up the warning that a script is unresponsive. Here is a [link](https://signup.zone/demo/class) to a demo page with this problem.

There is no problem when it is the only tab in the browser, or if there are a few tabs with simple pages in them.  It only happens when there are a few tabs already open to the left of it, and they use javascript heavily too.  It happens whether the developer console is open or not.

Strangely, you can drag the problematic browser tab out of the window it's in, and open it in a new window, and it will start running smoothly (after a page refresh).

I do not see this problem on a PC running Firefox 32.0.1 (without Firebug - I haven't tried it with).

Is this a Meteor problem, a Firefox or Firebug problem, or something else? Can I fix it?

I've noticed similar behavior with [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), which I doubt uses Meteor.

UPDATE - I just tried disabling Firebug on the Mac and restarting Firefox, and it seems to work fine now. So it looks like this is a problem with the Firebug add-on, even if the developer pane is not open - does that sound right?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is related to the Script panel in Firebug. I think it would be worth reporting this (I'll do if you want).

Comment: It looks like it is a problem with the Debugger API in Firefox. I have the same latency when using the Firefox built-in DevTools with the Debugger tab selected. Does disabling the Script panel in Firebug helps?

Comment: Hi fflorent, thanks for this - yes, disabling the script panel solves the problem too. If you can report it, that would be great - thanks!